Italian Culture .SE Proposal
Visiting Area51.SE I noticed several proposals for "cultural" sites such as this.
I think we should work on one for Italian culture too, which is undoubtedly appreciated all over the world.

Facendo una visita su Area51.SE ho notato varie proposte come questa.
Secondo me dovrebbe essercene una anche per la cultura italiana, che indubbiamente riceve interesse da tutto il mondo.

Remember to translate the question to English so that everyone can understand it.

It's an interesting proposal, but would there be enough activity in such a site?

@Charo done. Although some questions are in Italian...
We should at least think about it, with no rush. After all, the language site is still in beta, so if that goes well we can think about working on a culture page.

I think that the best thing is to post both in Italian and in English, so I've tried to keep the Italian version of the question. See http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/q/170/707.

I've just had this idea too. I think it would be great!
